# How to update data from a table given the ID using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make an update function in my form with codeigniter. This is what I have so far

controller

```
public function editMenu()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Menu Management';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' =>
    $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

    $data['menu'] = $this->db->get('user_menu')->result_array();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('menu', 'Menu', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
      //Must be in order
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
      $this->load->view('menu/index', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    else
    {
      $menu = $this->input->post('menu');
      $id = $this->input->post('id');

      $this->db->set('menu', $menu);
      $this->db->where('user_menu'. '.' .'id', $id);
      $this->db->update('user_menu');

      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">updated</div>');
      redirect('menu');
    }
  }
```

View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editMenuModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editMenuModal">Edit Menu</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="<?= base_url('menu/editMenu'); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p style="color:green">Enter new name</p>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" id="id" name="menu" value="<?= $m['id'] ?>" readonly>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="menu" value="<?= $m['menu'] ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The edit doesn't seem to work even though the **updated** message is shown after I finish inserting the new name. The data name stays the same. When I try to echo the query, it is giving me back `` UPDATE `user_menu` SET `menu` = 'd' WHERE `user_menu`.`id` IS NULL ``

I wanted to take in the ID from the form in the view code and pass it into the controller, where it is then used to execute the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two things

Change the name attribute of input having `id="id"`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" id="id" name="id" value="<?= $m['id'] ?>" readonly>
```

Change the update code

No need to use the table name here. But if you want to use do like this `$this->db->where('user_menu.id', $id);`

```
$menu = $this->input->post('menu');
$id = $this->input->post('id');

$this->db->set('menu', $menu);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('user_menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong name for the `id` input, change `name="menu"` to `name="id"` :

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" id="id" name="id" value="<?= $m['id'] ?>" readonly>
```